# Where to host a queue in a rackspace cloud deployment

Tags: deployment, queue, cloud

I am working on an application that consists out of a asp.net mvc front-end which call a bunch of webservices and those call onto sql server. The actions on the front-end could lead to a very large amount of jobs that need execution which I want to queue somewhere.

Due to the expected load profile of the application it makes sense to use a scalable infrastructure like the rackspace cloud. Now I am wondering where it would be best to queue the jobs. Queueing them on the front-end server means that the number of front-end servers can only be scalled back down once  the queues are processed which is a waste of resources if the peak load on the front-end is over we want to scale that down and scale up on machines that process the queue items.

If we queue them on the database server we are adding the load onto a single machine which in the current setup is already the most likely botleneck. How would you design this?

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on event sourcing and CQRS - in particular Greg Youngs 6hr presentation (http://www.viddler.com/v/dc528842) - it's aim is to alleviate the burden of these sorts of issues in a tried and tested way.

hth